# Holomorphic foliation and Morse-Bott function

Tags: differential-topology

Let $f$ be a holomorphic Morse-Bott function on a complex manifold $X$, with critical points being a compact complex manifold $Y$. Here Morse-Bott means the Hessian of $f$ is non-degenerate in the normal direction of $Y$.

Now my question is: whether $f$ determines a holomorphic foliation near $Y$?

I'm not sure if it is a stupid question, if so, please show me some references. Many thanks!